# Custom cakephp ConsoleLog message

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I am trying to get custom console logs such that 
instead of

```
2019-07-10 03:15:31 Error: [ParseError] syntax error, unexpected '}'
#0 /app/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/app/app/vendor...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\Controller\\...')
```

I want it in json format

```
{"Error":"[ParseError] syntax error, unexpected '}'"}
```

Currently, I have created a custom log adapter

```
// Log/Engine/ApplicationLog.php

    class ApplicationLog extends BaseLog
        {
        public $Logs;

        public function __construct($options = [])
        {       parent::__construct($options);

            // ...
        }

        public function log($level, $message, array $context = [])
        {
    //        $level = $this->getConfig('type');
            $this->$message = 'Test'.$message;
        }
        public function error($message, array $context = [])
        {
    //        return static::write(__FUNCTION__, '{"error":"'.$message.'"}', $context);
            return write('TESTESTSTESTSTEST');

        }
    }
```

with config as

```
// bootstrap.php
Log::setConfig('application', [
    'className' => 'Application',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'levels' => ['warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'],
    'file' => 'error',
    'engine' => 'console',
]);
```

I am trying to override the BaseLog error methods to alter the message as per my requirements but it doesn't call my custom message [after removing the engine parameter from the setConfig it did call my function].
Any suggestions are welcome & thank you.

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. Please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what _exactly_ you'd expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it working

```
// bootstrap.php
Log::setConfig('application', [
    'className' => 'Application',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'levels' => ['warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'],
    'file' => 'error'
]);
```

removed the engine parameter since it was interfering with the class functions

```
// Log/Engine/ApplicationLog.php
class ApplicationLog extends BaseLog
{
    protected $_defaultConfig = [
        'stream' => 'php://stderr',// similar to ConsoleLog
        'levels' => null,
        'scopes' => [],
        'outputAs' => null,
    ];


    protected $_output;

    public function __construct($config = [])
    {       parent::__construct($config);
        $config = $this->_config;
        if ($config['stream'] instanceof ConsoleOutput) {
            $this->_output = $config['stream'];
        } elseif (is_string($config['stream'])) {
            $this->_output = new ConsoleOutput($config['stream']);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('`stream` not a ConsoleOutput nor string');
        }

        if (isset($config['outputAs'])) {
            $this->_output->setOutputAs($config['outputAs']);
        }
    }

    public function log($level, $message, array $context = [])
    {
        $message = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", '{"'.$level.'":"'.$message.'"}');
        $message = $this->_format($message, $context);

       //$output = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . ucfirst($level) . ': ' . $message;
       //return (bool)$this->_output->write(sprintf('<%s>%s</%s>', $level, $output, $level));

        return (bool)$this->_output->write(sprintf('<%s>%s</%s>', $level, $message, $level));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use both the `engine` option and the `className` option, the former will overwrite the latter. The `engine` option is a relict from CakePHP 1.x/2.x, and I have no idea why it still exists.

Comment: Thanks!! I got rid of the engine, that way it at least started printing my test but in the browser any ideas how I may get it in the consoleLog without the engine parameter?